Novella about the accidential creation of a time machine, creator and two kids end up centuries in the past
Not a great read, but the author showed promise and I'd like to track this down...
Paperback from the 1990s(-ish).
An experimental physicist unwittingly builds a time machine that sends himself and two kids/tweens some 3000 years into the past. They only realize this after he notices the north star is Thuban.
One bit of the story that stuck with me is that they first appear inside a huge tree, and by looking at the rings he can tell which side of the spherical hole they cause is closer to the surface and they dig their way out in that direction.
The story was written by a physicist, who among other things, wanted to illustrate the difference between experimental and theoretical physics. The story ends with his colleague, a theorist, publishing a paper explaining the physics of the system.

I think you're thinking of Twistor by John Cramer, which is written by a physicist and features a grad student and two kids being teleported into a giant tree - it's not the past though - it's a "shadow matter" universe. From the wiki page
.

" After industrial espionage causes problems, physicist David Harrison
finds himself lost with two small children in an alternate universe
where the six-legged wildlife is dangerous and aggressive. David has
to find a way back home, while dealing with the spies that caused the
problems in the first place

This review confirms the giant tree

Industrial espionage goes awry and young physicist David Harrison and
two small children find themselves inside a giant tree in an alternate
Earth populated by strange, wonderful, and dangerous six-legged
wildlife


Interesting, I do not recall the wildlife, nor the sabotage angle, and I definitely recall the north star being different. But this has to be the book. I'm going to get a copy of Einstein's Bridge now.
